# failed to load images outside a root react front-end with nginx

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, react-router

I have a project with react using react-router and graphql. But when i tried load a route with any image saved to my backend graphql i have and error "cannot find module".

I have read some examples but not find any solution, how to configure my nginx to load these images that I have.

note: nginx only load the images enside a /build directory

These is my root directory:

```
   /var/www/production
         -front-end/build
         -back-end/images/....
```

These is my nginx config file:

```
 server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    root /var/www/production/front-end/build;

    index index.js index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name tukanasta.com  www.tukanasta.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some details, i.e. image referenced as `http://example.com/assets/image.jpg` should be loaded from `/var/www/production/back-end/images/assets/image.jpg` file?

Comment: These is one of errors: Error: Cannot find module './5e31b576358af7341127c011.png'

Comment: I use react router and I do not aim directly at the images, for example when I called tukanasta.com/promociones I should load a caruosel with some images.

Comment: Sorry, this error related to node.js, I don't think it can be solved with nginx config. Maybe someone with react-router experience can help you.